# Flask: streaming file with stream_with_context is very slow

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The following code streams a postgres BYTEA column to a browser

```
from flask import Response, stream_with_context

@app.route('/api/1/zfile/<file_id>', methods=['GET'])
def download_file(file_id):

    file = ZFile.query.filter_by(id=file_id).first()
    return Response(stream_with_context(file.data), mimetype=file.mime_type)
```

it is extreemely slow (aprox 6 minutes for 5 mb).

I am downloading with curl from the same host, so network is not the issue,
also I can extract the file from the psql console in less than a second,
so it seems the database side is also not to blame :

```
COPY (select f.data from z_file f where f.id = '4ec3rf') TO 'zazX.pdf' (FORMAT binary)
```

#### Update:

I have further evidence that the "fetch from the DB" step is not slow, If I write file.data to a file using

```
with open("/vagrant/zoz.pdf", 'wb') as output:
    output.write(file.data)
```

it also takes a fraction of a second. So the slowness is caused by the way Flask does the streaming.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to improve performance of Flask streaming? Having the same issue..

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue while using Flask to proxy streaming from another url using python-requests.

In this use case, the trick is setting the chunk_size parameter in iter_content:

```
def flask_view():
    ...
    req = requests.get(url, stream=True, params=args)
    return Response(
        stream_with_context(req.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)),
        content_type=req.headers['content-type']
```

otherwise it will use chunk_size=1, which can slow things down quite a bit. In my case the streaming went from a couple of kb/s to several mb/s after the increase in chunk_size.

Answer (score 1):

Flask can be given a generator that returns the whole array in a single yield and will "know" how to deal with it, this returns in milliseconds :

```
from flask import Response, stream_with_context

@app.route('/api/1/zfile/<file_id>', methods=['GET'])
def download_file(file_id):

    file = ZFile.query.filter_by(id=file_id).first()

    def single_chunk_generator():
        yield file.data

    return Response(stream_with_context(single_chunk_generator()), mimetype=file.mime_type)
```

**stream_with_context**, when given an array will create a generator that iterates through it and do various checks on every element, which causes a huge performance hit.